# Connecting RxJava Observables in layers

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have 3 layers in my app. Layer1 subscribes to Observable from layer2. Layer2 subscribes to layer3 in order to emit returned data to layer1.

Layer1

```
layer2.getData(data).subscribe(newData -> {Log.d("onNext", "returned");},
                    throwable -> {Log.d("onError", throwable.getMessage());});
```

Suppose layer3 has a method called downloadDataFromApi(data);

```
public Observable<Data> getData(String data) {
    return  Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Data>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Data> subscriber) {
            Data data = new Data();
            subscriber.onNext(data);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
            // Can't find a way to connect to layer3.
        }
    });
}
```

What do I need to do in layer2's getData() method? I basically want to have logics before returning Observable back to layer1.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you have 3 layers (presentation, business logic, data access).

So what you could do is the following:

```
class PresentationLayer {

    private BusinessLogicLayer layer;

    PresentationLayer() {
        layer = new BusinessLogicLayer();
    }

    public void showName() {
        layer.getNameWithoutRxPrefix()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(String name) throws Exception {
                        // show name somewhere
                        Log.d("PresentationLayer", "name: " +  name);
                    }
                });
    }
}

class BusinessLogicLayer {

    private DataAccessLayer layer;

    BusinessLogicLayer() {
        layer = new DataAccessLayer();
    }

    public Observable<String> getNameWithoutRxPrefix() {
        return layer.getName()
                .map(new Function<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(String name) throws Exception {
                        return name.replace("Rx", "");
                    }
                });
    }
}

class DataAccessLayer {

    public Observable<String> getName() {
        return Observable.just("RxAndroid");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I return an Observable in my data access layer (`getName`), and chain another method to it in my business logic method (`map`) before returning it to the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2):

Just return the `Observable` directly. Then layer1 handles subscription as usual.

```
class Layer2 {
    public Observable<Data> getData(String data) {
        return layer3.getData(data);
    }
}
```